# Removing the unwanted quotes and comma from particular column .csv file using C sharp

Tags: c#, ssis

I want to extract the data from comma separated .CSV file but this file contains a field with unwanted single quotes in between the words like ab"cd  .. it also contains unwanted comma in between .. could guys pleas help to remove the same from CSV file   using C # code

Thanks in advance.. :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: Show one of the lines you have (exactly, make sure all characters are shown in your question) same for a line as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

C# Code to Remove commas between double quotes in a CSV file.

```
 string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

    string[] lignes = contenu.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int i = 1; i < lignes.Length; i++)
    {
        // REMOVE COMMAS

        string[] values = csv.Split(new[] {','});

        // do something
    }

    reader.Close();
```